# What is the best way to send same report with different parameters using Windows File Share in SSRS 2012

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have SSRS report that have Parameter "Office". The parameter contain 20 different offices.

I need to create subscription and deliver this report in  Excel format to particular folder on a server.

The way I am going to do that is to create 20 different subscriptions and set each parameter as a default parameter. That way, it will run a report 20 times and deliver Excel spreadsheet to each directory.

My question, is any way to somehow avoid creating 20 subscriptions? Maybe there is a different way to achieve same result?

I am using Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Standard. As I know this version does not support Data-driven subscription.

Thanks

Comment: What edition of Reporting Services?

Comment: Standard edition. I dont think Data-driven subscription is available in Standard edition.

Comment: You are correct, that feature is only present in Enterprise and BI Editions

Comment: Do you know if its  can be achieved using Power BI ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help you [Simulate Reporting Services Data Driven Subscriptions on Unsupported Editions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4249/simulate-reporting-services-data-driven-subscriptions-on-unsupported-editions/)